# Outputting file details using ffprobe in ffmpeg AWS Lambda layer

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, ffmpeg, aws-lambda

I am trying to output the details of an audio file with ffmpeg using the ffprobe option. But it is just returning 'null' at the moment? I have added the ffmpeg layer in Lambda. can anyone spot why this is not working?

```
const { spawnSync } = require("child_process");
const { readFileSync, writeFileSync, unlinkSync } = require("fs");
const util = require('util');
var fs = require('fs');
let path = require("path");

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {

    spawnSync(
        "/opt/bin/ffprobe",
        [
            `var/task/myaudio.flac`
        ],
        { stdio: "inherit" }
        );
};
```

This is the official AWS Lambda layer I am using, it is a great prooject but a little lacking in documentation.

https://github.com/serverlesspub/ffmpeg-aws-lambda-layer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, I would recommend using NodeJS 8.10 over NodeJs 6.10 (it will be soon EOL, although AWS is unclear on how long it will be supported)

Also, I would not use the old style handler with a callback.

A working example below - since it downloads a file from the internet (couldn't be bothered to create a package to deploy on lambda with the file uploaded) give it a bit more time to work.

```
const { spawnSync } = require('child_process');
const util = require('util');
var fs = require('fs');
let path = require('path');
const https = require('https');


exports.handler = async (event) => {
    const source_url = 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b2/Bell-ring.flac'
    const target_path = '/tmp/test.flac'

    async function downloadFile()  {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const file = fs.createWriteStream(target_path);
            const request = https.get(source_url, function(response) {
              const stream = response.pipe(file)
              stream.on('finish', () => {resolve()})
            });
        });
    }

    await downloadFile()

    const test = spawnSync('/opt/bin/ffprobe',[
            target_path
        ]);

    console.log(test.output.toString('utf8'))

    const response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify([test.output.toString('utf8')]),
    };
    return response;
}
```

NB! **In production be sure to generate a unique temporary file as instances that the Lambda function run on are often shared from invocation to invocation, you don't want multiple invocations stepping on each others files! When done, delete the temporary file, otherwise you might run out of free space on the instance executing your functions. The /tmp folder can hold 512MB, so it can run out fast if you work with many large flac files**

Comment: This is looking promising :-) I am trying to output the duration and channels of the flac file. On my WIndows 10 install using ```-i``` gets this information. At the moment it just outputs the version of ffprobe

Comment: ```[
            "-i",
            target_path
        ]```

Comment: I edited the post and put an acutal flac file, for me, it returns "Duration: 00:00:03.00, start: 0.085333, bitrate: 1057 kb/s Stream #0:0: Audio: flac, 96000 Hz, stereo, s32 (24 bit)" as part of the output on lambda @Gracie

Comment: I'll have another go, just for reference these are the exact lines to extract both pieces of info
```ffprobe in.wav -show_entries stream=channels -select_streams a -of compact=p=0:nk=1 -v 0```

```ffprobe in.wav -show_entries stream=duration -select_streams a -of compact=p=0:nk=1 -v 0```

Comment: That's working now, getting an output. Just need to pop those two pieces of data in variables, but I try that tomorrow. A thoroughly great answer, thanks so much for your help, ticked.

Comment: I'll look into it. Btw, I edited the post more, the last version of the download handler didn't wait for the file to download before continuing, you should use the latest edit.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not fully familiar with this layer, however from looking at the git repo of the thumbnail-builder it looks like [child_process is a promise](https://github.com/serverlesspub/s3-lambda-ffmpeg-thumbnail-builder/blob/master/src/child-process-promise.js), so you should be waiting for it's result using .then(), otherwise it is returning null because it doesn't wait for the result.

So try something like:

```
return spawnSync(
    "/opt/bin/ffprobe",
    [
        `var/task/myaudio.flac`
    ],
    { stdio: "inherit" }
    ).then(result => {
      return result;
    })
    .catch(error => {
      //handle error
    });
```

Comment: That comes back with ```TypeError: spawnSync(...).then is not a function```

Comment: can you confirm "child_process" is a function in your code?